# Telerik RadDateTimePicker does not allow PM hours to be chosen

Tags: telerik

Im having a bug in the DateTimePicker widget.  When you select a time by clicking in the UI, it  disregards your selection and forces the time to be set in AM time.  As an example, select 3 PM in the UI and the result will be set to 3 AM

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker runat="server" ID="rdpEndDate" Width="100%" RenderMode="Classic">
                                        <Calendar runat="server">
                                            <SpecialDays>
                                                <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" ItemStyle-BackColor="LightGrey">
                                                </telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                                            </SpecialDays>
                                        </Calendar>
                                        <DateInput runat="server" DateFormat="d/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt" DisplayDateFormat="d/MMM/yyyy hh:mm  tt" LabelWidth="64px">
                                    <EmptyMessageStyle Resize="None" />
                                    <ReadOnlyStyle Resize="None" />
                                    <FocusedStyle Resize="None" />
                                    <DisabledStyle Resize="None" />
                                    <InvalidStyle Resize="None" />
                                    <HoveredStyle Resize="None" />
                                    <EnabledStyle Resize="None" />
                                </DateInput>
                                <DatePopupButton CssClass="" />
                                <TimeView runat="server"></TimeView>
                                    </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was just changing its culture, looking at some forums helped solve this problem, yet I still dont understand why it worked in other places and yet didnt work in this one. Heres the changes I made so it would work again:

> <telerik:RadDateTimePicker runat="server" ID="rdpDate"
> MinDate="1/1/1900" Width="100%" RenderMode="Classic" Culture="en-US">
>
>
> <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today"
> ItemStyle-BackColor="LightGrey">
> </telerik:RadCalendarDay>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>